# API Json Deserialize C# Class

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a Json response from an API.

The data looks like this.

```
 {
      "api": {
        "results": 1,
        "aaa": [
          [
            {
              "bbb": 1,
              "ccc": 85,
              "ddd": "this is  test1",
              "eee": "this is  test2",
              "fff": "orang",
              "ggg": "apple",
              "hhh": "this is test3",
              "iii": {
                "iia": 35,
                "iib": 27,
                "iic": 4
              },
              "jjj": {
                "jja": 18,
                "jjb": 16,
                "jjc": 2
              },
              "kkk": {
                "kka": 17,
                "kkb": 11,
                "kkc": 2,

              },
              "lll": 67,
              "mmm": 85,
              "nnn": "2019-05-04"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

and, for more information about Json schema for this case is

```
 {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "results": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "aaa": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and i have create a custom class to read the json content http://json2csharp.com/ :

```
public class Api
{
    public int results { get; set; }
    public List<List<>> aaa { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Api api { get; set; }
}
```

what is correct class for this json?
What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Take a look at this line public List<List<>> aaa { get; set; }
That just won't compile, needs to have a type, I'm assuming you could KeyValuePair?

Comment: Is wired to have a List in a List, with no defined object inside, are you sure that the json is correct? if you delete a pair of [ ], the generated class is really different

Comment: Json is modified enought to remove the meaning. I will recommend making a [mcve] with correct name. It's hard to know if aa bb cc are diferent property or if it should be deserialised to a dictionnary<string,string>.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a class for each object. so you must create a class for this section:

```
"items": {
            "type": "object"
         }
```

and then use this class in this line:

```
public List<List<Item>> aaa { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the schema you've provided, this should work:

```
public class Api
{
    public Dictionary<string, object>[][] Aaa { get; set; }
    public long? Results { get; set; }
}
```

But if you want to fully deserialize the class, you might use something like this:

```
public class FinalClass
{
    public Api Api { get; set; }
}

public class Api
{
    public long Results { get; set; }

    public Aaa[][] Aaa { get; set; }
}

public class Aaa
{
    public long Bbb { get; set; }

    public long Ccc { get; set; }

    public string Ddd { get; set; }

    public string Eee { get; set; }

    public string Fff { get; set; }

    public string Ggg { get; set; }

    public string Hhh { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, long> Iii { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, long> Jjj { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, long> Kkk { get; set; }

    public long Lll { get; set; }

    public long Mmm { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Nnn { get; set; }
}
```